# How to fix iPhone deployment target ? (App Store)

Tags: ios, ipad

So I tried to ship my iPhone app into the App Store. but it get rejected because when the App reviewer test my app they are using iPad and it seems my app is messed up.

and this was the rejection message:

> We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.3.1. Specifically, we were unable to Sign Up using an iPad.

So I searched that I need to make the deployment info devices into `Universal`. It works well on iPad when I tested out. But the problem is I'm shipping this app for iPad. and when I go to iTunes connect, they were asking for iPad screenshots.

[image]

So should I set the device deployment for iPhone or Universal?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are actually asking here. Do you want to know why it is not running on that version of iOS on an iPad? Do you want to know how to make the app an iPhone only app? Something else?

Comment: I want to know how to deploy only for iPhone. but at the same time when I got rejected by Apple, they are saying my app is not running well in iPad.

Comment: The app must work in iPad also. choose the devices iphone only and try to run your app in ipad in 1x and 2x view.

Comment: Here's something important to understand for iPhone-only apps. They must work as-is on the iPad. They will run in an "iPhone compatibility" mode. But in order to do this, your app must support 3.5" iPhones. If you can make your iPhone-only app run on the smallest iPhones, it will run on an iPad as-is.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The app must work in iPad also. choose the devices iphone only and try to run your app in ipad in 1x and 2x view.

Comment: it works but when I tried running it on iPad, seems like all the constraint are messed up. But when I set the device deployment into Universal, it's working perfectly fine

Comment: are you using size classes? if yes then correct your constraint Compact and Regular size class and upload it again with proper UI.

Comment: Don't just fix those constraints and then upload it again. Make sure you thoroughly test it on all possible devices, orientations, iOS versions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build for iPhone only, you will need to go to the project settings > General > Devices and choose "iPhone". If you choose "Universal" then you are building for both iPhone and iPad, which is why you need screen shots for the iPad as well. If you build for iPhone only, though, the app can still run on iPad, it will get scaled up.

As for the reason why it is not working on iPad using iOS 10.3.1, you'll have to run it on a device with that version of the OS and do some debugging. The information you gave here is not enough.